# java SimpleDateFormat does not work properly in hive custom UDTF

Tags: java, hadoop, hiveql

I created a custom hive UDTF named for example **compareDate()**.

And hive sql is:

```
select compareDate('2017092704','2017092706') from sometable;
```

Java Code of my UDTF is like:

```
...
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHH");
@Override
public void process(Object[] args) throws HiveException {
    String datestr1 = args[0].toString();
    String datestr2 = args[1].toString();
    try{
        sdf.parse(datestr1).getTime();
        ...
    } catch (ParseException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
}
...
```

And ParseExceptions were thrown in process:

```
Unparseable date: "2017092704" ...
```

I suspect it is a **encoding problem**, so i change my UDTF input parameter to IntWritable:

```
public void process(Object[] args) throws HiveException {
    String datestr1 = Integar.toString(((IntWritable) args[0]).get());
    try{
        sdf.parse(datestr1).getTime();
        ...
    } catch (ParseException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
}
...
```

And my hive sql changed to:

```
select compareDate(2017092704,2017092706) from sometable;
```

However i still get:

```
Unparseable date: "2017092704" ...
```

Comment: Be careful of how you use and define a `SimpleDateFormat` as it is not thread-safe

Comment: The date conversion is correct and also the `sdf` is configured properly. Could you log the date before parsing them?

Comment: thanks, @araknoid. In this circumstance it is fine ( different values are processed in serial in same worker)

Comment: @araknoid I did that by `System.out.println(datestr1); System.out.println(new String(datestr1.getBytes(),"UTF-8"))`. And they both output correct date string: "2017092704". And `System.out.println(new String(datestr1.getBytes(),"UTF-16"))` gave rubbish.